# How to filter through this properly?

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, foreach

I am wondering how to filter through a result like this properly. What I am doing results in problems. Obviously using a foreach on an array with a single item is not ideal but I don't know exactly how to do it any other way.

```
    // connect with the static file
    $json = file_get_contents('resources/assets/datafeeds/brewery_single.json');
    $obj = json_decode($json, true);

    // create brewery info
    foreach($obj['pages'] as $brewery) {
        foreach($brewery['results'] as $brewery) {

        }
    }
```

I've tried doing something like:

```
    foreach($obj['pages']['results'] as $brewery) {

    }
```

But I get an **Undefined index: result** errror like this.

Example data with only one result block, **my data has multiple:**

```
{
    "apiName": "brewery_single",
    "apiGuid": "d74e8aa2-4064-44b9-81de-2ceb150882c0",
    "generatedAt": 1452761620,
    "pages": [
        {
            "pageUrl": "http://www.brewery-website.com",
            "results": [
                {
                    "website": "www.brewery.com/",
                    "plaats": "Place",
                    "latlong": [
                        "53.657856",
                        "5.032597"
                    ],
                    "naam": "Brouwerij title",
                    "provincie": "Noord Brabant",
                    "afbeelding": "http://www.brewery.com/images/brewery/brewer.jpg",
                    "actief": "Yes",
                    "land": "Netherlands",
                    "adres": "<p><b>Adres:</b><br />Street 40 <br />2388 GP<br /> Province, Netherlands </p>",
                    "opgericht": "1990"
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

Hopefully somebody can help me out so I can properly get my data from an api.

Comment: What is the exact error that you get? And is the second code snippet correct? You're missing a single quote...

Comment: It is correct in my codebaseI updated it here. Sorry. I am getting a  Undefined index: results

Comment: You made it an object so you should use `->` instead of `['']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `pages` is an array of *potentially multiple* pages, each of which contains a `results` array of *potentially multiple* results. So indeed, two loops are in order:

```
foreach ($obj['pages'] as $page) {
    foreach ($page['results'] as $brewery) {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you're only ever interested in the first result, you can try to directly access it:

```
if (isset($obj['pages'][0]['results'][0])) {
    echo $obj['pages'][0]['results'][0]['plaats'];
}
```

But again, the point of this data structure appears to be to account for multiple results, so you may be missing out on some information if you only ever consider the first.

Consult the documentation (which hopefully exists) of that API for exact details on the returned data.

Comment: The result array only ever contains a single result so this works fine. Thanks for helping out. This pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error in your code near `['results]`

Change from

```
foreach($obj['pages']['results] as $brewery) {
```

into

```
foreach($obj['pages']['results'] as $brewery) {
```

There is no multiple arrays in `results` array. So why you need `foreach` there?

Anyways you can get value of `results` by providing exact `INDEX`.

For example: `echo $obj['pages']['results]['website'];`

Comment: Sorry I updated it in my post, it is correct in my codebase I typed it wrong here.

Comment: @Hassaan: it is an array, but in the snippet it contains only 1 entry. Foreach is valid...

Comment: @Hassaan so how do I get the data from the array properly do you have an example maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra check to see if the data that you want is in the array:

```
if (isset($obj['pages'])) {
    foreach($obj['pages'] as $brewery) {
        if (isset($brewery['results'])) {
            foreach($brewery['results'] as $brewery) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```